# Refer to field and assign some logic to that field

Tags: awk

I have input file with data as

```
cell   input     out    type      fun            level
AI20   A1,A2,A3    Z    comb    ((A1A2))          2
INV    I1         ZN    comb    (!I1)              1  
BUF  A1,A2,A3,B1  Z     comb    (!(((A1A2)A3)B1))  4
CLK    C          Z     seq      Cq                1
XOR    A1,A2,B1   Z     comb    (((A1A2)B1)        3
IAD    A1,A2,A3   Z     comb    (!((A1A2)A3))      3
INV    I1         ZN    comb    (!I1)              1
```

I want output as below

```
cell   ins    input                             out
AI20   i1    .A1(A),.A2(B),.A3(C)               .Z(n1)    
INV    i2    .I1(n1)                            .ZN(n2)    
BUF    i3    .A1(n2),.A2(1),.A3(0),.B1(0)       .Z(n3)    
CLK    i4    .C(n3)                             .Z(n4)    
XOR    i5    .A1(n4),.A2(0),.B1(0)              .Z(n5)    
IAD    i6    .A1(1),.A2(n5),.A3(0)              .Z(n6)    
INV    i7    .I1(n6)                            .ZN(X)
```

The logic is

> if it is first line of input file I.e `AI20` assign its inputs `A1,A2` to user defined `A and B` and assign it output to `n1`. For next line in input file assign `previous net n1` to one of input and `0/1` to other inputs of that line and assign its output to next net `n2` and so on. `n1, n2,n3 so on` are nets and can be assigned to an array which has no. Of rows equal to `no of rows in (input file)-1`(no. of rows exclude header row of input file). If it is last line or row of input file then assign that line or row output to `X`.
> `i1,i2,i3...` are instance name which has number of rows equal to  `no of rows of (input file)`.
>
> A,B,X are user defined. We can directly use them in code.  The term inside bracket for input is basically the one present in the previous line in output(). Exception will be for first line input and last line output whose () terms are directly defined.

I used code

```
awk ' { print $1 ;print "."$2"()"; print "."$3"()" file }'
```

This gives me, but how can I build logic for inside().

```
AI20   .A1(), .A2(),.A3()    .Z()
```

Comment: Yes.. basically it is like.. we go through the input file. If it is the starting line then, for its input assign A,B inside ```()``` so we get ```A1(A) A2(B)``` and for its output assign it ```n1``` so we get ```Z(n1)```. For 2nd row in file. Assign to any one of its input as ```n1``` in bracket so we get ```I1(n1)``` And assign rest input to 0,1 if it is present. For its output assign it to n2 in bracket i.e ```ZN(n2)``` and so on.

Comment: I dont know the max length of input. But we can check for ```,``` if it is there than we have input present and if it not there means its the end. The space was my misalignment problem,I corrected in question. ```A2(n5)``` is in second value in line 6 because we can assign ```n``` to any of the input not only to the starting one. ```0``` and ```1``` are assigned randomly for left over inputs. @Jonathan

Comment: So assigning `0/1` is totally random in `input` field? Also is assigning `n1, n2, n3..` also random to any of the input?

Comment: Yes.. ```0/1/n1,n2,n3...``` are assigned randomly to any input fields. But first we need to assign ```n1,n2..``` to input field and if inputs are left then we will assign ```0/1```to left input fields.

Comment: So instead of `.A1(1),.A2(n5),.A3(0)` even `.A1(n5),.A2(1),.A3(0)` would also be correct output? @NEHACHOUDHARY

Comment: Yes correct sir. Any combination all are correct.@anubhava

Comment: If it is first line of  file, I.e ```cell == AI20```, then its input should be directly assigned ```A,B,C``` in the code depending on how many inputs are there in first line. And if it is last line of file ```cell INV``` then its output should be directly assigned ```X```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk` script:

```sh
cat remap.awk

NR == 1 {
   print "cell   ins    input     out"
   next
}
id != "" {
   ++r
   print id, "i" r, s, "." out "(n" r ")"
}
{
   n = split($2, a, /,/)
   s = ""
   if (NR == 2) {
      ch =  65
      for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
         s = (s == "" ? "" : s ",") sprintf(".%s(%c)", a[i], ch++)
   } else {
      s = "." a[1] "(n" r ")"
      for (i=2; i<=n; ++i)
         s = s "," sprintf(".%s(%d)", a[i], i%2)
   }

   id = $1
   out = $3
}
END {
   if (r)
      print id, "i" r+1, s, "." out "(X)"
}
```

Then use it as:

```sh
awk -f remap.awk file.txt | column -t

cell  ins  input                         out
AI20  i1   .A1(A),.A2(B),.A3(C)          .Z(n1)
INV   i2   .I1(n1)                       .ZN(n2)
BUF   i3   .A1(n2),.A2(0),.A3(1),.B1(0)  .Z(n3)
CLK   i4   .C(n3)                        .Z(n4)
XOR   i5   .A1(n4),.A2(0),.B1(1)         .Z(n5)
IAD   i6   .A1(n5),.A2(0),.A3(1)         .Z(n6)
INV   i7   .I1(n6)                       .ZN(X)
```

Comment: Sir, the line ```s = s "," sprintf(".%s(%d)", a[i], i%2``` it will assign second row one input with ```n``` and for rest of input ```i%2``` will assign ```0/1``` correct.? But when  I run the code, ```0/1``` are not assigned to left inputs.

Comment: The output in your ans is what i am expecting,  but When I run the code am getting different output, ```0/1``` are not assigned to left inputs.

Comment: You can see a working demo here: https://ideone.com/g5vH7R It works with your sample data

Comment: Yes sir I checked it, it's working. Understanding the code. Thanks